# IEnumerable - my extension method

Tags: ienumerable

```
public static Record FindOrCreate(this IEnumerable<Record> ienumerable, string name)
{

        if (ienumerable.Where(element => element.Name == name).FirstOrDefault() != null)
            return ienumerable.Where(element => element.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<Record> result = ienumerable.Concat(new[] {new Record(name, "")});
            ienumerable = result;
            return ienumerable.Where(element => element.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
        }
}
```

I know there is no Add method to IEnumerable but I want to stay with IEnumerable instead of ICollection and in really rare cases I have to add something. My methodmalways returns null if it doesn't find element.

Code EDITED ! 
So, now result has all elements that I want, but method still return null object. I don't know if is it possible to switch objects in extension methods? (like I did ienumerable=result) ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to bend the `IEnumerable<T>` beyond it's purpose.

An `IEnumerable<T>` is just a sequence of elements and that's why `IEnumerable<T>` does not have an `Add<T>` method in it's interface. It's read only.

I would recommend changing your implementation of your extension method.

Comment: yeah, I know all this stuff but I really care to cheat on this one :)

Answer (score 1):

So the question is "how can I modify the code to not return null if the element isn't found, but return a new item"?

```
public static Record FindOrCreate(this IEnumerable<Record> source, string name)
{
    Func<Record,bool> pred = element => element.Name == name;
    return source.Any(pred) ? source.FirstOrDefault(pred) : new Record(name, "");
}
```

or

```
public static Record FindOrCreate(this IEnumerable<Record> source, string name)
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(element => element.Name == name) ?? new Record(name, "");
}
```

If the question is "how can I add a new item to the `IEnumerable<Record> source`, the short answer is you can't. The longer answer is cast the source to an `ICollection` and then add it. But at that point, you may as well just specify that you need an `ICollection<T>`

Note, I don't mean "you shouldn't" when I say "you can't", really, IEnumberable has no way to add items. Think about what it means to try to add a new number to the following `seq`

```
public IEnumerable<int> ShortSeq()
{
    yield return 0;
}
var seq = ShortSeq();
```

Comment: almost. return new item and put it in search source (put new item in IEnumerable<Record>)

Comment: Hey, I know I'm stubborn ;). But I edited my code and I was sure that it will work but it doesnt. but it's my last try, after that I let it go :P

Comment: Concat returns a new IEnumerable, it does **not** modify the source